# Pyruvate dehydrogenase: Apparently anomalous NAD/FAD redox reaction

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism, energy, energy-metabolism

Below is the mechanism for the reactions of the pyruvate dehydrogen complex, which oxidatively decarboxylates pyruvate and transfers the acetyl group to coenyzme A for further metabolism in the Krebs cycle.

[image: pyruvate dehydrogenase complex reactions]

The key point is that after $\ce{FAD}$ has reoxidized the dihydrolipoamide, the resulting  $\ce{FADH2}$  is reoxidized by $\ce{NAD+}$, which is reduced to $\ce{NADH}$.

I find the chemical energetics of this difficult to understand. According to standard tables of redox-potential for half reactions, $\ce{FAD}$ is a stronger oxidising agent, and a weaker reducing agent, than $\ce{NAD+}$, which is why it used in the succinate dehydrogenase reaction, for example. How, then, can it reduce $\ce{NAD+}$?

If $\ce{FADH2}$ is really able to reduce $\ce{NAD+}$ it should generate as much ATP in oxidative phosphorylation after oxidation of succinate to fumarate, despite the relatively low free energy change for that reaction. But that is absurd.

Comment: This is the most perceptive question on a biochemical topic that I have seen in the last twelve months, and deserves far more votes than it has received. A student, apparently new to biochemistry, has brought his chemical knowledge to bear and pointed to an apparent anomaly which most text-books ignore. The beauty of this question to me is that the explanation for this apparent anomaly illustrates the application of chemistry in a biological context. I have learnt from finding the answer to the question, and I hope the poster's interest in biological chemistry has been stimulated by it.

Comment: [1-2] IMO, and as I pointed out (politely) in the comments to the accepted answer, there is no thermodynamic problem here whatsoever. Why shouldn't FADH2 reduce NAD(+)? The reaction is reversible. It may be inferred from the standard redox potentials that the position of equilibrium greatly favours FAD reduction by NADH, but this does not mean that the reaction cannot (thermodynamically) proceed in the opposite direction. All that is required is a negative delta G. The position of equilibrium in ethanol dehydrogenase reaction,for example, greatly favours acetaldehyde reduction, and NADH ...

Comment: [2-2] can reduce acetaldehyde (to produce ethanol, as happens in yeast), BUT NAD(+) can oxidize ethanol (to give acetaldehyde, as happens in liver). When dealing with redox potentials and Gibbs free energy, one needs to sharply distinguish between standard conditions and actual conditions. For a reaction to proceed spontaneously (only) requires a negative delta G (or a positive redox potential), not a negative _standard_ delta G (or a positive _standard_ redox potential)

Comment: IMO a great reference to this problem is [Calculating apparent equilibrium constants of enzyme-catalyzed reactions at pH 7](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1539-3429.2000.tb00003.x) by [RA Alberty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_A._Alberty). The pdf is freely available

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Summary**
The redox potential widely quoted in text books for the half-reaction reduction of FAD to FADH<sub>2</sub> is indeed inconsistent with the observed direction of several reactions involving this coenzyme, including its reduction of NAD<sup>+</sup> in the dihydrolipoamide dehydrogenase reaction. The reason for this is that the value quoted is determined for free FAD in aqueous solution, which does not equate to the situation within the enzyme. In its tightly bound state in flavoproteins, the immediate environment (and, in some cases, covalent linkage) alters the affinity of the flavin ring for electrons, hence causing the redox potential to deviate from that in solution. The extent and direcction of this deviation differs in different flavoproteins.

**Restating the problem**
The basic idea of chemical theromodynamics is that reactions are energetic favourable if the (Gibbs) free energy change is negative (*see* e.g. [Section 14.1.1 of Berg *et al.*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22439/#A1943)). Although the actual free energy change, ΔG, is influenced by the relative concentration of the reactants, the usual starting point for assessing this in biochemistry is the ‘standard’ free energy change at pH7 and 25˚C — ΔG<sub>0</sub>′. In the case of oxidation/reduction reactions the standard oxidation–reduction potentials E<sub>0</sub>′ of each of the two half reactions are usually known (as they can be measured in solution), and one calculates the ΔG<sub>0</sub>′ from the oxidation–reduction potentials of the two half reactions, using the formula:

> Δ*G<sub>0</sub>′* = *–nF*Δ*E<sub>0</sub>′*

What is important for this discussion is not so much calculation of actual values, but determining their sign, as for a *negative* ΔG (reaction energetically favourable) a *positive* ΔE is required.
Let us consider an example using the much abbreviated version of [Table 18.1 of Berg *et al.* Biochemistry](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22427/#A2401), below:
Oxidant     Reductant       n     E´o (V)

```
Succinate   α-Ketoglutarate 2   – 0.67
NAD+        NADH            2   – 0.32
FAD         FADH2           2   – 0.22
Fumarate    Succinate       2   – 0.03
```

Consider one of the energy-generating oxidation reactions of the Krebs tricarboxylic acid cycle:
*α-ketoglutarate + NAD<sup>+</sup> → succinate + CO<sub>2</sub> + NADH*
This is made up of two half reactions:
*(+ 0.67 V) α-ketoglutarate  → succinate

(– 0.32 V) NAD<sup>+</sup> → NADH*

which gives an overall *ΔE<sub>0</sub>′ of  + 0.35 V*, i.e. a negative ΔG<sub>0</sub>′, which ***is*** consistent with the actual direction of the reaction and the production of energy. (Actual worked numeric examples can be found in [Berg *et al.*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22352/#A2495))
Now if we consider the dihydrolipoamide dehydrogenase reaction
*NAD<sup>+</sup> + FADH<sub>2</sub> → NADH + FAD*

The two half reactions are:
*(+ 0.22 V) FADH<sub>2</sub> → FAD

(– 0.32 V) NAD<sup>+</sup> → NADH*

This gives an overall *ΔE<sub>0</sub>′ of – 0.1V*, i.e. a positive ΔG<sub>0</sub>′, which, as the poster astutely points out, is ***not*** consistent with the direction of the reaction.

**Resolving the apparent anomaly**
Berg *et al.* do, actually, remark on this in [section 17.1.1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22427/#A2376) on the pyruvate dehydrogenase complex:

> This electron transfer to FAD is unusual, because the common role for
> FAD is to receive electrons from NADH. *The electron transfer potential*
> *of FAD is altered by its association with the enzyme* and enables it to
> transfer electrons to NAD<sup>+</sup>.

So, **how** is “the electron transfer potential of FAD altered by its association with the enzyme”? The quotation from Ghia and Massey<sup>1</sup> provides a general summary:

> The pyrimidine nucleus of the three-membered ring system is electron-deficient and can be viewed as an ‘electron sink’. In thermodynamic terms, any interaction which tends to lower its electron or negative charge density will increase the redox potential. The reduced flavin consists roughly of an electron-rich phenylenediamine moiety fused with a (4,5-diamino)-uracil. The latter is the moiety in which the negative charge (i.e. two electrons taken up by the oxidized flavin) is localized and, most importantly, stabilized. The degree to which this negative charge is stabilized or destabilized is an important factor governing the redox potential. Thus while a positive charge in the protein around the pyrimidine ring will contribute to increase the redox potential, the presence of negative charge or of a hydrophobic environment will lower it.

[image: Flavin ring]

In the specific case under consideration — dihydrolipoamide dehydrogenase — it has been established<sup>2</sup> that a positively charged lysine-57 sidechain (numbering for the *A. Vinelandi* enzyme) that increases the redox potential (with, perhaps, a small contribution from the backbone N of alanine-326):

[image: FAD environment in dihydrolipoamide dehydrogenase]
*[FAD environment in dihydrolipoamide dehydrogenase from A. Vinelandi. NAD is shown in light blue, except for the O and N atoms at the end of the flavin ring interacting with the protein. A section of the latter is shown as a wireframe in salmon pink without sidechains, except for lys57 and ala326. (Own diagram from 3LAD.pdb)]*

**A second apparent anomaly and its resolution**
In drawing attention to the apparent anomaly in the reduction of NAD<sup>+</sup> by FADH<sub>2</sub>, the poster suggested that this would imply one should by able to obtain enough energy to produce 3ATPs from reducing FADH<sub>2</sub>. The problem with this is that one actually needs FAD to have a lower redox potential to perform the reduction of fumarate that occurs in the Krebs cycle:

[image: succinate oxidation]

This can be seen by considering the redox potentials in the table above:
*succinate + FAD + → fumarate + FADH<sub>2</sub>*

The two half reactions are 
*(–0.22 V) FAD → FADH<sub>2</sub>

(+0.03 V) succinate → fumarate*

Thus, there is an overall *ΔE<sub>0</sub>′ of – 0.19V*, i.e. a positive ΔG<sub>0</sub>′ — another anomaly!

[Berg *et al.*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22427/#A2401) are rather coy on this one. They do not comment, but in their Table 17.2 of free energy changes in the steps of the TCA cycle — where all the other values are given as exact figures — they quote  “~0” for this step.

This implies a *higher (more positive)* redox potential for FAD than the –0.22 quoted in the table — certainly not the lower one of dihydrolipoamide dehydrogenase.

I turns out that this is, in fact, the case. In succinate dehydrogenase (aka as fumarate reductase) FAD is covalently attached to a histidine residue (his44 in *E. coli*) at the other side (position 8) of the flavin ring<sup>3</sup>.

[image: FAD environment in succinate dehydrogenase]
*[FAD environment in succinate dehydrogenase from E. coli. NAD is represented as previously. A section of the latter is shown as a wireframe in salmon pink without sidechains, except for his44 and a backbone N. (Own diagram from 1L0V.pdb)]*

An extensive review<sup>4</sup> of the redox potentials of covalently and non-covalently bound flavoproteins shows that covalent attachment increases the redox potential.

**Final observations**

- Chemistry is a powerful tool for understanding biology at the
  molecular level. Biology is subject to the laws of chemistry, but the
  chemistry of the special environments encountered (protein interiors,
  spaces compartmented by membranes) need taking into consideration,
  something that the classically trained chemist, new to the subject,
  may not fully realized.
- Elementary textbooks often have to walk a fine line between
  comprehensibility and truth. The student of biological chemistry
  should realize that the initial simplifications that enabled him to
  get an overall grasp may mask greater complexities. One of the
  intellectual satisfactions in science can be found by resolving these
  complexities in a rationale manner.

**References**
<sup>1</sup>[Ghisla and Massey (1989) *Mechanisms of flavoprotein-catalysed reactions*](https://febs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/j.1432-1033.1989.tb14688.x)
<sup>2</sup>[Maeda-Yorita *et al. Biochemistry* (1994) **33**, 6213–6220](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bi00186a022)
<sup>3</sup>[Kim and Winge (2013) *BBA* **1827**, 627–636](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0005272813000169?via%3Dihub)
<sup>4</sup>[Heuts *et al.* (2009) *FEBS Journal* **276**, 3405–3427](https://febs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1742-4658.2009.07053.x)

Comment: Your answer is gold! I really enjoyed it. The concept you used is called symphoria or Neighbouring group participation or anchimeric assistance in organic chemistry texts. I was familiar with this concept in the field of organic chemistry and how it was used to determine the mechanism of reactions But I'd never seen the actual use of this in biochemical studies. Great job!

Comment: (+1) [1-3] Although I don't like criticizing such an excellent answer, I think the following point is relevant: to the sentence "... which, as the poster astutely points out, is not consistent with the direction of the reaction." must be added the qualification "when the reactants are in the standard state". But what determines spontaneity is the _actual_ reduction potential (or Gibbs free energy), not the standard reduction potential (unless standard conditions happen to apply). ...

Comment: [2-3]  That is, the conditions within the active site may well favour oxidation FADH(2)  by NAD(+) without the need to postulate any change in oxidation/reduction potential of cofactor by binding to the enzyme. To take an example given by Berg: the LDH reaction.  When reactants are in the standard states (1M), the _reaction greatly favours pyruvate reduction_. But in the Cori cycle, depending on _in vivo_ conditions, the enzyme may act either as a pyruvate reductase OR as a lactate dehydrogenase.

Comment: [3-3] If we were to consider only standard reduction potentials we would conclude that the enzyme _always_ acts a pyruvate reductase.  Similarly, although the point about isocitrate dehydrogenase is a good one, but MDH is surely a counter-example? The position of equilibrium of the MDH reaction _greatly favours oxaloacetate reduction_ (when reactants are in the standard state, oxaloacetate reduction is the 'spontaneous' reaction), but in the TCA cycle MDH functions as a _malate dehydogenase_, contrary to the above analysis.

Comment: @Sam Thank you for your kind words. This sort of effect is fundamental to other aspects of protein chemistry, especially catalysis, where the environment of an amino acid residue can alter its properties.

Comment: @user338907 — I agree that an unfavourable ΔGo can be 'overcome' by, e.g. the removal of products producing a favourable ΔG. In a metabolic pathways, this may be especially relevant. In approaching this question I was aware of this possibility. However this does not seem to be the case for dihydrolipoamide dehydrogenase, as there is no "pull" on the NADH produced. I personally was surprised at the extensive literature on the redox properties of FAD, and somewhat ashamed at my ignorance. For me the difference between the diffusible NAD and tightly-bound FAD has acquired another dimension.

Answer (score 0):

In the example of dihydrolipoamide dehydrogenase from A. vinelandi, the interaction of the FADH2 with the protein should ideally *decrease* the reduction potential, (not increase it). If the reduction potential is decreased, then the protein-bound FADH2 will be better able to donate e- to NAD+. Thus, it doesn't make sense to position positively charged aa residues next to the FADH2 in this particular example provided from A. vinelandi.